# Memory leaks in JMeter Java process. It is consuming >90% CPU and 80% Memory while running a Test with 400 TPS for 48 hours

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jmeter

I am running a JMeter script with 400 TPS and 48 hours, it is REST API script.

**JMeter Version : 5.6.2**

**JMeter script configuration given below:**

```
Threads : 500
Ramp Up : 100
Duration: 48 hours
TPS     : 400 Using Throughput Shaping Timer
```

Gradually during the test I observe that CPU and Memory Utilisation keeps on increasing on the Load Generator VM where JMeter is running. **After 36-40 Hours it becomes unresponsive**

```
CPU Utilisation >90% and Memory Utilisation >80%
```

Load Generator where the JMeter script is running having 8 CPU and 16GB RAM from which I have configured JMeter with -Xmx1g and -Xmx10g heap.

I have taken the Thread and Heap Dump with following Analysis:

Process Details confirming the High CPU and Memory Utilization using **TOP Command**

```
top - 11:38:00 up 54 days, 12:01,  1 user,  load average: 8.83, 7.98, 8.01
Threads: 541 total,   8 running, 533 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 97.9 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16247380 total,  2010332 free, 13876416 used,   360632 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4190204 total,  3953660 free,   236544 used.  2001252 avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
107296 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:12.27 GC Thread#1
107297 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:08.55 GC Thread#2
107298 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:09.84 GC Thread#3
107299 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:08.98 GC Thread#4
107300 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:12.21 GC Thread#5
107301 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:11.67 GC Thread#6
107302 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 99.9 79.2 293:10.00 GC Thread#7
107273 sam_user  20   0   17.1g  12.3g  20572 R 94.1 79.2 293:08.49 GC Thread#0
```

Heap Analysis after taking heap dump:

**Problem Suspect 1:**

```
One instance of org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded by 

org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @ 0x580103ba0 occupies 83,61,68,864 (17.61%) bytes. 

The memory is accumulated in one instance of 

java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[], loaded by <system class loader>, which 

occupies 83,61,68,384 (17.61%) bytes.

Keywords

org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @ 0x580103ba0
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
```

**Problem Suspect 2:**

```
1,20,38,109 instances of java.lang.String, loaded by <system class loader> occupy 

1,82,80,04,808 (38.50%) bytes.

These instances are referenced from one instance of 

java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[], loaded by <system class loader>, which 

occupies 83,61,68,384 (17.61%) bytes.

Keywords

java.lang.String
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
```

**Problem Suspect 3:**

```
1,20,16,586 instances of org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger, loaded by 

org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @ 0x580103ba0 occupy 1,53,81,23,008 (32.39%) bytes.

These instances are referenced from one instance of 

java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[], loaded by <system class loader>, which 

occupies 45,16,41,568 (9.51%) bytes.

Keywords

org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @ 0x580103ba0
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
```

**I assume this is Apache JMeter issue, could you please provide a solution for this?**

Answer (score 3):

Your "analysis" shows only that heap usage is too high and [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) takes a lot of resources.

If you only have a single [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and observe memory utilization getting higher over the time it's indeed a problem in JMeter and you should [report it via JMeter Github](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

However it could be the case it's your script which causes this behaviour, i.e. you're creating new [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and never removing them. Or you're using the same virtual users for 48 hours and I don't think it's a valid use case. Or you're using badly configured [Groovy scripts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) which generate new classes each time they're being called. Or you're using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) which don't add any value and only accumulate data.

So if the issue can be reproduced given you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) and without any external components/code - it's a JMeter problem. Otherwise it's your test design problem.

Comment: Indeed, a "nearly full" heap is liable to *cause* the GC to take a lot of resources!

Answer (score 1):

You do appear to have a memory leak in your JMeter instance.  However, there isn't enough evidence to justify an "assumption" or conclusion that this is caused by a JMeter bug.

The only clue that I can see is that the leaked objects appear to be a huge number of `Logger` instances and an (almost) matching number of strings in a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  Based on the `Logger` class name, it looks like you are using log4j2, and log4j2 uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` to implement the logger registry.  So one possible explanation is *something* is creating an excessive number of distinct `Logger` instances; i.e. with distinct names.

I did a quick trawl of the JMeter issue tracker for issues that mention "memory leak".  None of them were obvious matches to your symptoms, but I could have missed something, and you've given us minimal information on your JMeter scripts.  (You can review the issues for yourself [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20%22memory%20leak%22).)

> ... could you please provide a solution for this?

We can't do that based on the information that you have provided.

If I had this problem, I would use the heap dump analyzer to look at the entries in that `ConcurrentHashMap`.  Assuming that it is the logger registry map, there should be a big clue in the keys.